# Detecting address chunk within a word document

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I have a word document with some paragraphs and address details within it. I used textract to extract the sentences of this document line by line into a list. What i want to do is to detect the complete address chunk as one whole sentence string. The address template is not fixed and can or cannot have all the details some times,  how can i achieve that ?

the input document looks like -

```
some paragraph1

Employee’s address: Mr. A John Doe
9 hackers way
a state in US
2192
Telephone: 1411567323
Telefax: - 
E-mail: someemail@gmail.com

some paragraph 2
next page
some paragraph 3
```

what i want the complete address chunk to be detected is -

```
Employee’s address: Mr. A John Doe
    9 hackers way
    a state in US
    2192
    Telephone: 1411567323
    Telefax: - 
    E-mail: someemail@gmail.com
```

Comment: I suggest adding some cases/examples of how each of the details can vary. For example, what sort of telephone and telefax numbers are you expecting (no. of digits, whitespace, area codes etc.)? Are the addresses only US addresses and are they expected to be formatted consistently? Are the street numbers and names always on a separate line to the state and post code? The robustness of the solution you require is ambiguous at present. A more detailed question will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 1):

If the text file's structure is constant, you don't need to use `nlp`, just Python with some hardcoded detections like this:

```py
lines = []
with open("textfile.txt") as textfile:
    lines = textfile.readlines()

address_line = None
telephone_line = None

for i in range(len(lines)):
    if "Employee’s address:" in lines[i]:
        address_line = i
    elif "Telephone:" in lines[i]:
        telephone_line = i

if address_line and telephone_line:
    address = lines[address_line:telephone_line]

address = ", ".join([address_line.rstrip() for address_line in address]).lstrip("Employee’s address:")
```

The result of this script is:
`'Mr. A John Doe, 9 hackers way, a state in US, 2192'`

Comment: well that could have been the case if the address template is fixed. The address template is random in the sense it can begin with some other text and some time can or not have telephone or fax or email details

Comment: I've seen that you edited the question and included this information, good. You could also include some other examples of address to be detected - it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to find cannot be achieved 100% as the text changes but, you can extract quite a few useful stuff from the text.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp(text)

text='''Employee’s address: Mr. A John Doe
    9 hackers way
    a state in US
    2192
    Telephone: 1411567323
    Telefax: - 
    E-mail: someemail@gmail.com'''

print("Noun phrases:", [chunk.text for chunk in doc.noun_chunks])
print('emails: ' ,[token for token in doc if token.like_email])
print('numbers: ', [token for token in doc if token.like_num])

#output
Noun phrases: ['Employee’s address', 'Mr. A John Doe\n    9 hackers', 'a state', 'US\n    2192\n    Telephone', '1411567323\n    Telefax', 'E', '-', 'mail']
emails:  [someemail@gmail.com]
numbers:  [9, 2192, 1411567323]
```

Comment: Looks promising but what happens when the address text is between two paragraphs where the paragraphs can have noun chunks within them ?

Comment: @NaN I am not sure that regural expressions or pre-trained models can solve your problem. The amount of place references and numbers in large text files can be overwhelming. If this part of the process is crucial to your application maybe consider connecting to an maps API that will allow you to identify all addresses in any give scenario.